# How to draw mxGraph endarrow as double ended

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Used the XML structure to draw the graph using JavaScript library, I want to draw an edge having a double ended arrow, i.e, endArrow=open; two times.

I used in style as **style="endArrow=open;"**, but I'm getting the endarrow only once, I need to two times. something like this **--->>**

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom marker, register it, then use it for the start/endArrow style(s) as needed.

The [markers example](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/markers.html) demonstrates how this is done.

[Add and define the marker](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/v3.7.1/javascript/examples/markers.html#L39) using mxMarker.addMarker() and the [canvas API](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxXmlCanvas2D-js.html) to define the graphics operations using the end point of the line (pe) and vector normal the direction of the marker (nx, ny).